# Unable to access openapi-generator-cli.jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar, openapi-generator

I am trying to execute the jar file but it gives me the error.

[image]

I have tried many solutions but couldn't work for me. How can we solve this? The openapi-generator-cli.jar file is located in the home directory.

Comment: Does it work if you use `/` instead of `\` in paths?

Comment: @Helen Thank you. It solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

On non-Windows operating systems, use `/` (not `\`) as a path separator.